# Filter specific row from one data table to other data table

Tags: vb.net, datatable, rowfilter

I am using Windows Application. I have two data tables called "dt1" and "dt2".

In "dt1" i have some rows like

```
ID Name Group
1  A1    G1
2  A2    G1
2  A2    G2
3  A3    G2
3  A3    G1
4  A4    G2
5  A5    G2
```

AND In second table "dt2",

```
ID NAME  
1  A1
2  A2
3  A3
4  A4
5  A5
6  A6
```

Now i want rows of "dt2"  from filtered row "dt1" say id - 1,2 which is also present in "dt2".

So basically i want rows for one data table from other data table which is filtered.

Can any one give some idea how to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient and easiest would be to use [`Linq-To-DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977) and `join` both tables:

```
Dim result = From r1 In dt1.AsEnumerable()
             Join r2 In dt2.AsEnumerable()
             On r1.Field(Of Int32)("ID") Equals r2.Field(Of Int32)("ID")
             Select r2
```

If you want the result, what is an `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)`, as `DataTable`:

```
Dim tblResult = result.CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: thanks Tim for quick reply. but i want row filtered in dt1 and then get those rows from dt2.

Comment: @BrijeshPatel: How do you want to filter dt1? You could also use Linq([`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb738042#wheresimp2)).